# in python test this string("\x04\x01\x00PÀcö60\x00") with startswith or re, but returns false

Tags: python, string, hex

I am working on a webserver access log analysis tool. Sometimes i get malformed requests hitting the web server. I want to be able to identify these. However when trying to test whether this string "\x04\x01\x00PÀcö60\x00" starts with \x0. Python reports no match.

I am doing:

```
>>> t = "\x04\x01\x00P\xC0c\xF660\x00"
>>> t.startswith('\\x0')
False
```

What am i missing here? I tried regex as well, but no dice. :(

I even tried to strip the slashes, but i cannot. What wizardry is this?

```
>>> t.replace("\\", "")
'\x04\x01\x00PÀcö60\x00'
>>> t
'\x04\x01\x00PÀcö60\x00'
```

Comment: I appreciate your answers. However this leaves me with the conundrum of testing whether this string has hex literals in it. That is the reason i was testing for \x0 or \x...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because if you'd look at the first character you'd actually see this:

```
>>> t = "\x04\x01\x00P\xC0c\xF660\x00"
>>> t
'\x04\x01\x00P\xc0c\xf660\x00'
>>> t[0]
'\x04'
>>> t.startswith('\\x0')
False
>>> t.startswith('\\x04')
False
>>> t.startswith('\x04')
True
>>>
```

So the first character is represented by a hex value of `04` while you tested it with a value of `0`.

Answer (score 3):

The first character of the input string `'\x04\x01\x00P\xC0c\xF660\x00'` is `'\x04'` as the escape sequence has the format `\xhh`.

`'\\x0'` in your example is actually a string composed of 3 characters: `'\'`, `'x'` and `'0'`. Compare:

```
>>> len('\x04')
1
>>> len('\\x0')
3
```

So the correct check would be `t.startswith('\x04')`:

```
>>> t = '\x04\x01\x00P\xC0c\xF660\x00'
>>> t.startswith('\x04')
True
```

See the [Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to break the string up by `\\`:

```
t = "\x04\x01\x00P\xC0c\xF660\x00"
t = [i for i in t if i != "\\"]
```

`t` contains:

```
['\x04', '\x01', '\x00', 'P', '\xc0', 'c', '\xf6', '6', '0', '\x00']
```

To access the first character, you will have to provide a hex character that is not `0`, but `04`:

```
if t[0] == "\x04":
   do_something()
```